# C Sending files with Berkeley socket

Tags: c, sockets, networking

I'm trying to send files on a Client-Server application written in c.

Client should upload files and server should receive files.
Client side :

```
if(fstat(fd,&file_stat) < 0){
    perror("Fstat error");
    return -1;
}


FILE *filepointer = fopen(filename,"rb");

if(filepointer == NULL){
    perror("Opening file error");
    return -1;
}

strcat(sendbuf,"8"); // option number
strcat(sendbuf,client_account.user); //user who is sending a file
strcat(sendbuf,"p1.txt"); // file name
printf("sendbuf : %s\n",sendbuf );
if(write(sock_fd,sendbuf,strlen(sendbuf)) < 0 ){
    perror("Writing error");
    return -1;
}

/* Check server's answer */
if((nread = read(sock_fd,buffer,sizeof(buffer))) < 0){
    perror("Reading error");
    return -1;
}
buffer[nread] = '\0';
printf("Buffer : %s : %d",buffer,atoi(buffer));
if(atoi(buffer) != GENERIC_OK){
    printf("Error occurred\n");
    return -1;
}

sprintf(file_size,"%lld",file_stat.st_size);

/* Writing file size */
if((nwritten = write(sock_fd,file_size,sizeof(file_size))) < 0){
    perror("Writing error");
    return -1;
}

memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
/* Check second server's answer */
if((nread = read(sock_fd,buffer,sizeof(buffer))) < 0){
    perror("Reading error");
    return -1;
}
buffer[nread] = '\0';
printf("Buffer : %s : %d",buffer,atoi(buffer));
if(atoi(buffer) != GENERIC_OK){
    printf("Error occurred\n");
    return -1;
}


while(1){

    nbytes = fread(sendbuf,1,sizeof(sendbuf),filepointer);
    /* There are bytes to send */
    printf("Sendbuf : %s \n" , sendbuf);
    if(nbytes > 0){
        write(sock_fd,sendbuf,nbytes);
    }

    if(nbytes < 256){
        if(feof(filepointer) || ferror(filepointer))
            break;
    }
}
```

Server side :

```
... first buffer is received well ...`
/* WRITE TO CLIENT TO CONTINUE */
if(write(sock_fd,"500",strlen("500")) < 0){ /*GENERIC OK*/
    perror("Writing error");
    return -1;
}

memset(recvBuf,0,sizeof(recvBuf));
/*RECEIVING FILE SIZE */
if((nread = read(sock_fd,buffer,sizeof(buffer)))< 0){
    perror("Reading error");
    return -1;
}
buffer[nread] = '\0';

file_size = atoi(buffer);
printf("file size : %d\n",file_size);



if((fd = open(filename, O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_TRUNC,  S_IRWXU)) < 0){
    perror("File opening error"); /* file already exists */

}

recv_file = fopen(filename,"wb");
if(recv_file == NULL){
    perror("Opening error");
    return -1;
}

remaining_data = file_size;/*i think processes are blocking on while loops*/
while(((nread = read(sock_fd,recvBuf,sizeof(recvBuf))) > 0) && remaining_data > 0){ 
    recvBuf[nread] = '\0';
    printf("%d bytes received : %s \n",nread,recvBuf);
    fwrite(recvBuf,1,nread,recv_file);
    remaining_data -= nread;
}

if(nread < 0){
    perror("Reading error");
}
```

I've tried to use `sendfile` function but I'm on Mac OS and it's not supported. Have you got any advice for me?

It should go like this :

1) client sends a buffer to server announcing it's going go send a file with its name - OK

2) server receives this buffer and sends a generic ok code to client - OK

3) client sends the size of the file to the server - OK

4) server receives this buffer and sends a generic ok code to client - OK

5) client read stuff from file and sends it to the server - NOT OK

6) server receives stuff from the client and writes stuff into the file - NOT OK

Comment: Perhaps you could be more specific about how the programs misbehave?

Comment: It's a bit odd that you use a mixture of POSIX I/O (`read()` and `write()`) and standard stream I/O functions (`fread()` and `fwrite()`), but as long as you are consistent about which you use with which file, that shouldn't be an actual problem.  Myself, though, I'd just use POSIX I/O throughout.

Comment: @JohnBollinger it blocks on the while loop...Client should send the buffer full of stuff to the server but it doesn't seem to happen because the server is blocked ( on the read function i think) too.

Comment: the code needs to clear sendbuf[] to all '\0' before any calls to strcat() and to make it easy for the receiver to parse the data, either sendbuf needs to be an implementation of a struct and place data into each field or place some delimiter (like a ',' or ':') between each field

Comment: this line, in the client: 'if(nbytes < 256){' is using some 'magic' number,  It should be using 'sizeof(sendbuf)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line, in the server,

```
while(((nread = read(sock_fd,recvBuf,sizeof(recvBuf))) > 0) && remaining_data > 0){
```

is trying to read first, without having checked that `remaining_data >0`. The result is a read operation after all the file is transfered.

Suggest using a `while(remaining_data>0) { select()/read() }`, where the `select()` has a reasonable timeout parameter and causes an exit of the loop when a timeout occurs.

Answer (score 1):

this code:

```
if((fd = open(filename, O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_TRUNC,  S_IRWXU)) < 0){
    perror("File opening error"); /* file already exists */

}

recv_file = fopen(filename,"wb");
if(recv_file == NULL){
    perror("Opening error");
    return -1;
}
```

is opening the output file, in the server, twice, without an intervening `close()`. This is probably not what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have left out some of the relevant code, but very likely the key problem is in the server's `while` condition:

```
while(((nread = read(sock_fd,recvBuf,sizeof(recvBuf))) > 0) && remaining_data > 0){
```

Note that it will *always* attempt to read data, even if it has already read the expected number of bytes.  If the client holds the connection open (maybe it's waiting for a response from the server) then no EOF condition will be detected, and you have a deadlock.

Swapping the order of the conditions should resolve that problem, at least for well-behaved clients.  Note, however, that even with that change, you could still get a deadlock if the client sends fewer bytes than it promises, yet holds the connection open.  A *malicious* client could intentionally exhibit that behavior to perform a DoS against your server.

Answer (score 0):

Also, 'read(sock_fd,buffer,sizeof(buffer)', followed by 'buffer[nread] = '\0';' will overflow the buffer by 1 if the the full 'sizeof(buffer)' bytes are received.

'file_size = atoi(buffer)' - not guaranteed to work since you don't know if the whole buffer has been received.

Also endianness issue with same.